# couldn't bring arm xen alive : Unable to allocate first memory bank

Tags: xen

I'm currently working on bring xen alive on an ARM64 platform.
The xen always pops up "Unable to allocate first memory bank" when it tries to allocate 128 MB for DOM0 (512MB on target platform).
I use **pagealloc_info()** to dump memory info, finding there is only small amount of heaps.
Does any one have idea??

```
- UART enabled -
- CPU 00000000 booting -
- Current EL 00000008 -
- Xen starting at EL2 -
- Zero BSS -
- Setting up control registers -
- Turning on paging -
- Ready -
(XEN) Checking for initrd in /chosen
(XEN) RAM: 0000000000000000 - 000000001ffe0fff
(XEN)
(XEN) MODULE[0]: 0000000001ff2000 - 0000000001ff3000 Device Tree
(XEN) MODULE[1]: 0000000003000000 - 0000000003600000 Kernel       earlyprintk console=ttyS0,115200 cma=16m@64m
(XEN)  RESVD[0]: 0000000001ff2000 - 0000000001ff3000
(XEN)
(XEN) Command line: console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk loglevel=4
(XEN) Placing Xen at 0x000000001fc00000-0x000000001fe00000
(XEN) Update BOOTMOD_XEN from 0000000000200000-0000000000302d81 => 000000001fc00000-000000001fd02d81
(XEN) Domain heap initialisedPhysical memory information:
(XEN)     Xen heap: 0kB free
(XEN)     heap[01]: 8kB free
(XEN)     heap[02]: 8kB free
(XEN)     heap[03]: 16kB free
(XEN)     heap[04]: 32kB free
(XEN)     heap[05]: 64kB free
(XEN)     heap[06]: 128kB free
(XEN)     heap[07]: 256kB free
(XEN)     heap[08]: 512kB free
(XEN)     heap[09]: 1024kB free
(XEN)     heap[10]: 2048kB free
(XEN)     heap[11]: 4096kB free
(XEN)     heap[12]: 8192kB free
(XEN)     heap[13]: 16328kB free
(XEN)     Dom heap: 32712kB free
(XEN)
(XEN) Bad console= option 'ttyS0'
(XEN) Bad console= option '115200'
 Xen 4.6.0-rc
(XEN) Xen version 4.6.0-rc (tom_ting@(none)) (aarch64-linux-xgcc (Realtek ASDK64-4.9.3 Build 2180) 4.9.3 20150413 (prerelease)) debug=y Wed Sep  2 20:16:44 CST 2015
(XEN) Latest ChangeSet: Wed Sep 2 17:15:27 2015 +0800 git:3cad003-dirty
(XEN) Processor: 410fd034: "ARM Limited", variant: 0x0, part 0xd03, rev 0x4
(XEN) 64-bit Execution:
(XEN)   Processor Features: 0000000000002222 0000000000000000
(XEN)     Exception Levels: EL3:64+32 EL2:64+32 EL1:64+32 EL0:64+32
(XEN)     Extensions: FloatingPoint AdvancedSIMD
(XEN)   Debug Features: 0000000010305106 0000000000000000
(XEN)   Auxiliary Features: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
(XEN)   Memory Model Features: 0000000000001122 0000000000000000
(XEN)   ISA Features:  0000000000010000 0000000000000000
(XEN) 32-bit Execution:
(XEN)   Processor Features: 00000131:00011011
(XEN)     Instruction Sets: AArch32 A32 Thumb Thumb-2 Jazelle
(XEN)     Extensions: GenericTimer Security
(XEN)   Debug Features: 03010066
(XEN)   Auxiliary Features: 00000000
(XEN)   Memory Model Features: 10201105 40000000 01260000 02102211
(XEN)  ISA Features: 02101110 13112111 21232042 01112131 00011142 00010001
(XEN) FIXME, temporary WA
(XEN) Using PSCI-0.2 for SMP bringup
(XEN) CPU0 has no enable method
(XEN) cpu0 init failed (hwid 0): -22
(XEN) Generic Timer IRQ: phys=30 hyp=26 virt=27 Freq: 33000 KHz
(XEN) GICv2 initialization:
(XEN)         gic_dist_addr=00000000ff011000
(XEN)         gic_cpu_addr=00000000ff012000
(XEN)         gic_hyp_addr=00000000ff014000
(XEN)         gic_vcpu_addr=00000000ff016000
(XEN)         gic_maintenance_irq=25
(XEN) GICv2: 128 lines, 4 cpus, secure (IID 0200143b).
(XEN) Using scheduler: SMP Credit Scheduler (credit)
(XEN) Allocated console ring of 16 KiB.
(XEN) Brought up 1 CPUs
(XEN) P2M: 40-bit IPA with 40-bit PA
(XEN) P2M: 3 levels with order-1 root, VTCR 0x80023558
(XEN) I/O virtualisation disabled
(XEN) *** LOADING DOMAIN 0 ***
(XEN) Loading kernel from boot module @ 0000000003000000
(XEN) Allocating 1:1 mappings totalling 128MB for dom0:
(XEN) Physical memory information:
(XEN)     Xen heap: 0kB free
(XEN)     heap[01]: 8kB free
(XEN)     heap[02]: 8kB free
(XEN)     heap[03]: 16kB free
(XEN)     heap[04]: 32kB free
(XEN)     heap[05]: 64kB free
(XEN)     heap[06]: 128kB free
(XEN)     heap[07]: 256kB free
(XEN)     heap[08]: 512kB free
(XEN)     heap[09]: 1024kB free
(XEN)     heap[10]: 2048kB free
(XEN)     heap[11]: 4096kB free
(XEN)     heap[12]: 8192kB free
(XEN)     heap[13]: 16016kB free
(XEN)     Dom heap: 32400kB free
(XEN)
(XEN) ****************************************
(XEN) Panic on CPU 0:
(XEN) Unable to allocate first memory bank
(XEN) ****************************************
```